# Find examples that f(x) is discontinuous at $x_0$ $\in$ X but 1.$|f(x)|$ is continuous at $x_0$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, continuity

$Find$ examples that $f(x)$ is discontinuous at $x_0$$\in X$  $but$

$1$.$|f(x)|$ is continuous at $x_0$.

$2$.$f^2(x)$ is continuous at $x_0$.

For first one I am thinking about $f(x)$ = \begin{cases}1 &x\geq0\\-1 & x<0\end{cases}

but can't bring any example for $second$ one.

Comment: By $f^2(x)$ you mean to composition? Or $f^2(x)=f(x)\times f(x)$

Comment: $f^2(x)=f(x)\times f(x)$.

Comment: So you are right, your example is true for both, because $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}: f^2(x)=1^2=1$ or $=(-1)^2=1$ which is continuous

Comment: $\chi_\mathbb{Q}$ may be useful in this kind of exercises

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Draw the graph and see what happens, how $|f|$ can be continuous even though $f$ isn't: They meet the $y$-axis at exact opposite values.

Make it so the two horizontal lines are further apart. Make it so that they are sloped instead of horizontal. Make it so they are curved instead of straight. There are plenty of ways to make more examples.

Here are a few concrete formulas:
$$
x\mapsto\cases{-2& if $x<0$\\2& otherwise}\\
x\mapsto\cases{x-1& if $x<0$\\1-x& otherwise}\\
x\mapsto\cases{x^2-1& if $x<0$\\x^2+3x+1& otherwise}
$$

Comment: How one would come up with your $3$-rd example? Without plotting every quadratic function.

Comment: It is not difficult to tailor quadratic functions to hit the $y$-axis at $\pm1$. You just choose the constant term to be $\pm1$. Also note that you can pick and mix right and left parts. There is no reason you can't have it straight on one side and curved on the other, for instance.

Comment: I understand thank you..